# how to clear my output buffer or server cache after each loop iteration

Tags: php, out-of-memory, outputcache

I have a script written in PHP:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$ttl; $i++){
 execute some code
 clear output cache

}
```

I want to clear server cache on each loop iteration, actually I am getting contents parsing it and then proceed to the next content for parsing.

Currently my scripts gives out of memory error, I want to get ride of it, by clearing the server cache but how?

Comment: you may need to increase max_execution_time time and memory_limit in php.in

Answer (score 0):

Use unset($unset_parm) function..
if db object use $db_obj->free_result();

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it will resolve your problem, but what you are looking for is in the manual...

Use ob_start() to start buffer:
https://www.php.net/ob_start

Use ob_end_flush() to send and end buffer:
http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ob-end-flush.php

You could use ob_flush() instead of it to not end the buffer output:
http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ob-flush.php

I advise to optimize your script before...

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking what you can do from PHP is call [flush()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) (or ob_flush()) which flushes the output buffer. But this doesn't necessarily make the output go to the client since the web server may buffer the output aswell (also in case of compression modules and so on).

You may also need to check php.ini output_buffering option. In the flush function link linked there are some interesting considerations in the comments, check them out!