# Clear buffer output without ob_start() and ob_end_flush()?

Tags: php, wordpress, output-buffering

I am wondering if there is a way to clear/delete/clean buffer output after some output has already been written, but where ob_start() has not been invoked.

(I.e. in the instance in which I.e [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449285/how-to-clear-my-output-buffer-or-server-cache-after-each-loop-iteration/21449378#21449378) is not possible because ob_start has not been called.)

Specifically, I've got a Wordpress plugin that I want to specify a certain output, but it being a plugin it runs only after Wordpress has begun to send output. I tried ob_get_clean(), but it didn't have any affect.

Is this possible?

Comment: ob_end_whatever only works if ob is actually active. beyond that, your only option is `flush()`.

Comment: @MarcB I think op wants to *un-flush* and clear already-written output

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to "undo" what's been flushed to the output buffer after the fact.  No, this isn't possible.